# i.stack.imgur images gone?

Tags: bug

I thought photos on `https://i.stack.imgur.com/` weren't meant to expire? Or at least, not expire for a very long time without views?

[image]

It seems strange that two images on [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/265196/speed-up-microsoft-windows-dns-server) are gone, but one survives...

Comment: Wouldn't this be better asked on MSO ?

Comment: @Iain - Apparently the devs also check here. I got knuckle-wrapped for migrating these sorts of questions from msf to mso ;)

Comment: Sorry for not linking to the original question, it was 6am my time when I posted it!

Comment: Has this been sighted again since? If not, it might just have been a one-time event - possibly due to some data loss at imgur.

Comment: URL: http://serverfault.com/questions/265196/speed-up-microsoft-windows-dns-server  issue still occurs.

Answer (score -3):

Imgur's FAQ mentions image-retention [here](http://imgur.com/faq#long), and basically says 1 view in 6 months will keep an image around. Though there is possibly a different "policy" in-place for i.stack.imgur.com, as they have/had a "Pro" account.

Though this question is two years old, the most recent outage was October 4th, 2014, and only affected the v2 API ([see here](http://status.api.imgur.com/post/99606028931/10-3-2014-api-v2-outage))

Comment: There *is* a different policy for i.stack.imgur.com: images are retained forever (at least if they're linked in a post on Stack Exchange). [sf] isn't the only site where some images have seemingly vanished, or even vanished for some users only (some kind of screwup in imgur's replication?), it's a rare but reproduced bug.